# Validating bunch of form data in php - Is it necessary?

Tags: php

I am making a survey website. I just want to know if it's really necessary to validate each and every POST data into the database by using `isset` and `!empty`. I have around 30 columns and I find it redundant.

Is there any cleaner way than this?

EDIT:

And how about if I have optional fields? How do I come about that?

Comment: No it won't `[null, null, null]` is not `empty()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this such way:

PHP 5.5:

```
if(!empty(array_filter($_POST)))
{
   //there are non-empty fields in $_POST
}
```

PHP <5.5:

```
$filtered = array_filter($_POST);
if(!empty($filtered))
{
   //there are non-empty fields in $_POST
}
```

this difference is because before PHP 5.5 [`empty()`](http://php.net/empty) was not able to accept non-variables (i.e. expressions, for example)

*Edit*: if you have some optional fields, then you can deal with this, for example, with having list of mandatory fields:

```
$array     = ['one'=>36, 'two'=>null, 'three'=>'data', 'four'=>0];
$mandatory = ['one', 'three'];

$data = array_intersect_key($array, array_flip($mandatory));
if(!empty($data))
{
   //all mandatory fields are not empty
}
```

Comment: How about if I have optional fields?

Comment: Then you need to decide which of them are optional and separate them (check the edit)

Comment: Hey man. Will test this out. This seems like a genius ID.

Well anyway, just to make things clear. Mandatory array is where I put the required fields by using the name attributes right?

Comment: Yes, it contains keys of original array (so `$_POST` in your case) which must be not empty

Comment: How about if I have a html input element generated with javascript due to a click/change event (i.e answering a question that leads to a follow up question, which must be a required field).

Comment: And what's the difference?